# How to get multi line result from serial port

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, serial-port

I'm working with winform project and trying to send a command to the serial port and receive data from it. I'm expecting a multi-line response, but using the following code I'm getting only the first line of the response. I don't want to use `ReadExisting`.

```
{
    SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM5");

    mySerialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
    mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
    mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
    mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
    mySerialPort.DtrEnable = true;
    mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;

    mySerialPort.Open();

    var command = Command.Authentication.GetStringValue();
    mySerialPort.WriteLine(command);               

    mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(_serialPort_DataReceived);

    string _response = mySerialPort.ReadLine();

    mySerialPort.Close();
}
```

---

```
void _serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    sp.ReadLine();
}
```

My response looks like:

> ```
> REQ: SUCCESS
> REQ: MAC_ADDR:000D6F111C5DB14C
> REQ: FWINFO: Build 01
> REQ: HWINFO: Gen3 R0c
> ```

I've tried:

```
{
    _serialPort = new SerialPort(
        _currentSerialSettings.PortName = Home.PortName,
        _currentSerialSettings.BaudRate,
        _currentSerialSettings.Parity,
        _currentSerialSettings.DataBits,
        _currentSerialSettings.StopBits);

    _serialPort.Open();

    //send command
    _serialPort.WriteLine(Command.Get_Device_List.GetStringValue());

    Thread t = new Thread(ReadThread);            
    t.Start(_serialPort);
}

private void ReadThread(object context)
{
    SerialPort serialPort = context as SerialPort;

    while (serialPort.IsOpen)
    {
        string inData = serialPort.ReadLine();
        Debug.WriteLine(inData);                
    }
}
```

Here are the two issues:

1. I want to get data in upper method, not in `ReadThread`.
2. It’s not giving the last data.

Am I missing something?

*Side Note: If I use `mySerialPort.ReadLine();` multiple times then i'm able to catch the whole response, but response may vary by command. And currently it's crashing on `ReadLine` while data is not present*

Comment: Subscribing the `.DataReceived` event is probably the best approach, but `.ReadLine()` is not your friend here. Just `.Read()` the input into a buffer and strip it of the line feeds you get, if needed.

Comment: Lacking a [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to know what a good answer would be. It doesn't help that your question isn't internally consistent. First you say that you only get the first line of data, then you say you are only missing the last line of data. It's also not clear what you want to do with the results (just display it, or do you need a way to know when a given response is complete?). Please improve the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try code below.  Uses Asynchronous Read and waits for the return at end of line before processing a command :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM5");

            _serialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
            _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
            _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            _serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
            _serialPort.RtsEnable = true;

            _serialPort.DataReceived += (AsyncRead);
            _serialPort.Open();


        }
        string inputData = "";
        private void AsyncRead(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort serialPort = sender as SerialPort;
            string inData = serialPort.ReadExisting();
            inputData += inData;

            int returnIndex = inputData.IndexOf('\n');
            if(returnIndex >= 0)
            {
                string command = inputData.Substring(0, returnIndex);
                //remove command from inputData
                inputData = inputData.Substring(returnIndex + 1);

                //test if command is just a return
                if (command.Length > 0)
                {
                    ProcessCommand(command);
                }
            }
        }
        private void ProcessCommand(string inputLine)
        {
        }

    }
}
```

---

Code with queue and timer

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication8
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static List<string> queue = new List<string>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Timer timer1 = new Timer();
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Interval = 500;
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM5");

            _serialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
            _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
            _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            _serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
            _serialPort.RtsEnable = true;

            _serialPort.DataReceived += (AsyncRead);
            _serialPort.Open();


        }
        string inputData = "";
        private void AsyncRead(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort serialPort = sender as SerialPort;
            string inData = serialPort.ReadExisting();
            inputData += inData;

            int returnIndex = inputData.IndexOf('\n');
            if (returnIndex >= 0)
            {
                string command = inputData.Substring(0, returnIndex);
                //remove command from inputData
                inputData = inputData.Substring(returnIndex + 1);

                //test if command is just a return
                if (command.Length > 0)
                {
                    queue.Add(command);
                }
            }
        }
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (queue.Count > 0)
            {
                string command = queue[0];
                queue.RemoveAt(0);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn’t seem to use asynchronous reads, just a normal synchronous ReadLine. Also I doubt that IndexOf is working as the new line characters were already consumed by the ReadLine function, which I’m almost sure of doesn’t re-emit them.

Comment: It is asynchronous due to the code being inside the DataReceived Event.  I forgot to change ReadLine() to ReadExisisting() which fixes the problem with IndexOf().

Comment: @jdweng: thanks for the answer! Currently I'm getting output in multiple part, how can get whole output at once?

Comment: I tested code a found one error.  Had to remove the first parameter (zero) from following : inputData = inputData.Substring(returnIndex + 1);  If code still doesn't work then the return character need to be modified ('\n').

Comment: I added 2nd version of code which does the processing using a timer and a queue :

Answer (score 1):

I few things to try

1. To make this asynchronous you want to use the DataReceived event
2. You should listen to the DataReceived event before you send the command.
3. The DataReceived event works with a property called **ReceivedBytesThreshold**.  In my example code i've set it to 1.  This means that if there is one byte or more in the serial buffer, the DataReceived event is raised.

You'll notice that in the DataReceived event you want to read every byte of data in the buffer as fast as possible.

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var serial = Setup();

        // send your command from here
        //var command = Command.Authentication.GetStringValue();
        //serial.WriteLine(command);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }



    static SerialPort Setup()
    {
        SerialPort serialport = new SerialPort("COM5");

        serialport.BaudRate = 115200;
        serialport.Parity = Parity.None;
        serialport.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        serialport.DataBits = 8;
        serialport.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        serialport.DtrEnable = true;
        serialport.RtsEnable = true;
        serialport.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;


        serialport.DataReceived += serialPort_DataReceived;
        serialport.Open();
        return serialport;
    }

    private static void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var s = (SerialPort) sender;
        int n;
        var data = new List<byte>();
        do
        {
            n = s.BytesToRead;
            var buffer = new byte[n];

            try
            {
                var size = s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                data.AddRange(buffer);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

        } while (n > 0);


        // you should raise your own event passing your data to your ui to exit this method
        // for demo only
        var yourdata  = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(yourdata);

    }
}
```